# Is there any way to add the result/output of multiple ansible tasks to the same file on the Ansible Controller node?

Tags: ansible

I have a requirement to store the output of all the anisble tasks to some file (output.log, in the below example) on the Ansible **controller node**. I tried to implent it this way.

```
- name: Playbook to store the output of two tasks to the same file
  hosts: test
  tasks:
  - name: task_1
    shell: command_1
    register: output_1

  - name: save output_1 using copy module
    copy: 
      content: {{ output_1.stdout_lines }}
      dest: ./output.log
    delegate_to: localhost

  - name: task_2
    shell: command_2
    register: output_2

  - name: save output_2 using copy module
    copy: 
      content: {{ output_2.stdout_lines }}
      dest: ./output.log
    delegate_to: localhost
```

The problem is that by the time the playbook completes the execution, the **output.log file** has  has only the output of the last task. I understand each time I use a copy module, it is replacing the old content.

Is there any way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the pattern of the registered variables

```yaml
  out_pattern: '^out_\d+$'
```

Execute the tasks and register the output

```yaml
    - command: echo command_1
      register: out_1
    - command: echo command_2
      register: out_2
```

Get the values of all registered variables and map the attribute *stdout_lines*

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        log: "{{ lookup('vars', *q('varnames', out_pattern))|
                 map(attribute='stdout_lines')|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  log:
    - [command_1]
    - [command_2]
```

Create a dictionary of all hosts and variables *log*

```yaml
  log_all: "{{ dict(ansible_play_hosts|
                    zip(ansible_play_hosts|
                        map('extract', hostvars, 'log'))) }}"
```

and write it into a file on the controller

```yaml
    - copy:
        dest: /tmp/out.log
        content: "{{ log_all|to_yaml }}"
      run_once: true
      delegate_to: localhost
```

---

Example of a complete playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: test

  vars:

    out_pattern: '^out_\d+$'
    log_all: "{{ dict(ansible_play_hosts|
                      zip(ansible_play_hosts|
                          map('extract', hostvars, 'log'))) }}"

  tasks:
    - command: echo command_1
      register: out_1
    - command: echo command_2
      register: out_2

    - set_fact:
        log: "{{ lookup('vars', *q('varnames', out_pattern))|
                 map(attribute='stdout_lines')|list }}"
    - debug:
        var: log|to_yaml

    - block:
        - debug:
            var: log_all|to_yaml
        - copy:
            dest: /tmp/out.log
            content: "{{ log_all|to_yaml }}"
      run_once: true
      delegate_to: localhost
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -l test_11,test_13

PLAY [test] ***********************************************************************************

TASK [command] ********************************************************************************
changed: [test_13]
changed: [test_11]

TASK [command] ********************************************************************************
changed: [test_11]
changed: [test_13]

TASK [set_fact] *******************************************************************************
ok: [test_11]
ok: [test_13]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [test_13] => 
  log|to_yaml: |-
    - [command_1]
    - [command_2]
ok: [test_11] => 
  log|to_yaml: |-
    - [command_1]
    - [command_2]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [test_11 -> localhost] => 
  log_all|to_yaml: |-
    test_11:
    - [command_1]
    - [command_2]
    test_13:
    - [command_1]
    - [command_2]

TASK [copy] ***********************************************************************************
ok: [test_11 -> localhost]

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
test_11: ok=6    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test_13: ok=4    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

The log file

```yaml
shell> cat /tmp/out.log 
test_11:
- [command_1]
- [command_2]
test_13:
- [command_1]
- [command_2]
```

Comment: Can you please let me know what is the purpose of  "*q('varnames', out_pattern)" ?

Comment: If you read doc [lookup vars](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/vars_lookup.html#ansible-builtin-vars-lookup-lookup-templated-value-of-variables) the [parameter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/vars_lookup.html#parameter-_terms) will tell you it is: `The variable names to look up`. If you want to take a look on your own nothing can prevent you from evaluating `{{ query('varnames', out_pattern) }}`.